# How to get data from R to pandas

Tags: python, r, pandas, rpy2

In a jupiter notebook I created some 2-d-list in R like

```
%%R
first <- "first"
second <- "second"

names(first) <- "first_thing"
names(second) <- "second_thing"

x <- list()
index <- length(x)+1
x[[index]] = first
x[[index +1]] = second
```

a `%Rpull x` does not return the nice representation but rather a `ListVector`. How can I convert it into something nicer e.g. a dict / pd.Dataframe? So far I had no luck following http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/r_interface.html
[image: pull from R]

## edit

The list I want to convert is a 2-d list like `results` the updated code snipped from above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just slice the `ListVector`:

```
%Rpull x
pd.DataFrame(data=[i[0] for i in x], columns=['X'])
```

[image]

If you want a dictionary instead:

```
dict([[i,j[0]] for i,j in enumerate(x)])
{0: 'first', 1: 'first'}
```

Comment: Instead of X I would like to get key - value how do I achieve this? I want to deal with the names() attribute? e.g. my i is a labelForKPI \n 0.xx_numericValue

Comment: your suggesting with the dict works pretty great, except that the "names" of the parameters are lost. How can I keep these?

Comment: But that just changed the order? because the names e.g. names(first) <- "first_thing" still are lost.

Comment: The point is if you enumerate i,j the j contains the list-elem (rpy2.floatVector) including the label.

Comment: It turns out that a j.names returns the name and a str.split('"')[1] hands me the desired value.

Answer (score 0):

Since you created an R list (rather than, say, a data frame),
the Python object returned is a `ListVector`.

R lists can have duplicated names, making the conversion to a `dict` something that cannot be guaranteed to be safe.

Should you feel lucky, and wanting a dict, it is rather straightforward.
For example:

```
 from rpy2.robjects.vectors import ListVector
 l = ListVector({'a':1, 'b':2})
 d = dict(l.items())
```

Comment: Indeed a conversion in R to a dataFrame helps a lot. However there are problems with the names.  confMatrix <- table(data,results)

err <- (confMatrix["J","N"]+confMatrix["N","J"])/sum(confMatrix)  
acc <- (confMatrix["J","J"]+confMatrix["N","N"])/sum(confMatrix)  

results <- list(err,acc) is the type of 2-d-list I would like to get back into python